# representar en Json un filter().values()

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Amigos, he estado tratando de representar esto en JSON pero no he podido:

```
miguel <QuerySet [<Libro: hunger games>, <Libro: sherlock holmes
jose <QuerySet [<Libro: divergente>, <Libro: sherlock holmes>]>
```

Este es el código que genera ese resultado que quiero representar en JSON:

```
def listado_libro(request):
    consulta1=Autor.objects.all().prefetch_related("autores_libros")
    for l in consulta1:
        print(l.nombre,l.autores_libros.all())

    consultajson= serializers.serialize("json",consulta1,fields=("nombre","autores"))
    return HttpResponse(consultajson,content_type="application/json")
```

En pocas palabras basado en estos modelos:

```
class Autor(models.Model):
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    apellido=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    cedula=models.CharField(max_length=8,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Libro(models.Model):
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    autores=models.ManyToManyField(Autor,related_name="autores_libros")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Tienda(models.Model):
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    libros=models.ForeignKey(Libro, related_name="libros_tienda")
    autores=models.ForeignKey(Autor,related_name="autores_tienda")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Quiero que la respuesta JSON sea los libros junto con los nombres de sus autores. hasta ahora no he podido representar los valores de la tabla relacionada, he probado con:

```
Autor.objects.values("nombre","autores__nombre")
```

Y me da el error de que el objeto `dict` no tiene atributo meta.

Mi resultado si `Autor.objects.only` en vez de values no me muestra los valores del nombre.

No he podido lograr mostrar valores de otra tabla en respuesta JSON. Lo he logrado en Python como tal imprimiendo con un bucle `for` y en la API de base datos con `values()`. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Se me ocurre que puedes importar el modulo json y utilizar el metodo dumps pasandole una lista.
`import json
    
    consultajson = json.dumps(list(consulta1))` Por otro lado, la consulta que te da el error, creo que no expresa lo que buscas, creo que debería ser `Libro.objects.values("nombre","Autor__nombre")`

Comment: muchas gracias hermano, me ayudo mucho usar el json.dumps ya me estoy acercando mas al resultado que deseo para luego consumir con axios de vue js la url json y hacer filtrados en los selects que es mi objetivo general. muchas gracias hermano, me ayudo mucho usar el json.dumps ya me estoy acercando mas al resultado que deseo para luego consumir con axios de vue js la url json y hacer filtrados en los selects que es mi objetivo general.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias Cecilio alonso me ayudo mucho tu sugerencia. comparto el resultado para que pueda servidr de ayuda a otro usuario aprendiz jeje.

```
def listado_libro(request):
    consulta1=Libro.objects.values("nombre","autores__nombre")
    consultajson=json.dumps(list(consulta1))
    return HttpResponse(consultajson,content_type="application/json")
```

lo cual arroja este resultado  en la paticion json

```
0   
nombre  "hunger games"
autores__nombre "miguel"
1   
nombre  "divergente"
autores__nombre "jose"
2   
nombre  "sherlock holmes"
autores__nombre "miguel"
3   
nombre  "sherlock holmes"
autores__nombre "jose"
```

te indico que probe Autores__nombre y no funciono, aunque ya sabia que me daria error colocar el nombre del modelo tal cual no funcionaria, he estado leyendo la documentacion django para saber por que exigen el nombre del modelo en minuscula cuando lo quieres utilizar como base para seguir un campo de otra tabla relacionada. el hecho es que funciona, te lo agradezco.

ahora lo que me queda hacer lo veo mas facil que es colocar en un solo registro los dos autores, por manera de organizacion y para una mejor visualizacion, que el libro que tenga dos o mas autores lo muestre en un solo registro json en este caso que "Sherlock holmes" no se repita si no que diga en su registro que esta anclado a dos autores: miguel y jose. pero esto que aprendi ya es un avance, muchas  gracias.